# Missing `node_modules` in Docker Container

Tags: node.js, docker, dockerfile, npm-install

I'm building a docker docker image for my Node.js application using the following `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM keymetrics/pm2:latest

RUN apk add --no-cache --update alpine-sdk python

# Bundle APP files
COPY package.json .

# Install app dependencies
ENV NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL warn
RUN npm install
RUN npm rebuild bcrypt --build-from-source

COPY . .

# Show current folder structure in logs
RUN ls -al

EXPOSE 3000
VOLUME /app/uploads

CMD [ "pm2-docker", "start", "pm2.json" ]
```

The issue is that the `node_modules` folder is not present in docker containers created from this image hence the application encounters an error won't run.

I have `node_modules` in my `.dockerignore` file but since I'm installing the necessary packages in the build process (`RUN npm install`), this shouldn't cause an issue.

Comment: Maybe the issue is with `COPY . .` that overwrites everything `npm install` has installed? Try replacing `COPY package.json .` with `COPY . .`, since your `package.json` should be copied using this command too.

Comment: @vfsoraki that's not the case. I've tried commenting the `COPY . .` section out but `node_modules` is still missing.

Comment: do in one RUN the npm, something like `RUN npm install && npm rebuild bcrypt --build-from-source`

Comment: check this doc https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/dockerfile_best-practices/

Comment: @user2915097 didn't work either.

Comment: @KayvanMazaheri Did you find the solution to this please?

Answer (score 0):

Then why don't you create this directory at build (ie adding the following line in your `Dockerfile` before `RUN npm install`) ?

`RUN mkdir <workdir>/node_modules`

(Replace `<workdir>` with the actual default working dir of the `keymetrics/pm2` image)

Answer (score 0):

I would say it is a directory issue.
You will want to set

```
ENV ROOT /usr/src/app
WORKDIR ${ROOT}
```

before

```
# Bundle APP files
COPY package.json .
```

example:

```
FROM node:8

ENV ROOT /usr/src/app
WORKDIR ${ROOT}

COPY package*.json ./

RUN yarn -i --quiet

# Bundle app source
COPY . .

ENV NODE_ENV development

CMD yarn run start:dev

EXPOSE 3000
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue, related to invalid package.json file, especially `name` field. After removing white spaces in `name` field, it created node_modules properly. So maybe pay attention if you have such errors.
[image]